# Raster image outside Grass screen, How to get it inside from start?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, area

I'm new in Grass and need some help!

I have created a LOCATION based on the coordinate system in which I want my data to be projected. So far I'm being able to Import & display the raster image (Tiff Image). However, to see this image have to click several times in zoom-in/out, I understand this is because the data is somewhere out of the "screen" but still inside the LOCATION. Is there to get this image inside de screen from the start?

**Location created:**
proj=UTM
datum=wgs84
zone=30
towgs84=0,0,0,0,0
no_defs=defined

**The Geo-TIFF image (MOD13Q1-NDVI and MOD13Q1-EVI ): was reprojected using MRT-Modis:**
-UTM
-Resampling: nearest Neighbor
-utm zone: 30
-datum=wgs84
-UL 39.9999 / -13.05407
-LR 29.9999/ 0.0

Despite creating few locations to get this data "inside the screen", couldn't make it. Don't know where my mistake is.

Comment: you need to run `g.region rast=name_of_your_raster` see here for more details: http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to run `g.region rast=name_of_your_raster`

check the GRASS Wiki page on [computational regions](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region) for more details.

Comment: Many thanks. Will follow the instruction on this tutorial.

Comment: Hi @dmci: the instruction you linked has worked perfect! I have raster on the screen from the start!. My further step is to extract a smaller image from this big one. I tried using R.region setting nort, south, east and west values of the smaller area (reflect the geographic boundaries) but only get the same image narrower in width and longer in high. Thanks

Comment: see `g.region` .